# duplica filas mi query sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo este query el cual me deberia de traer solo 2 filas pero me trae 4

```html
select Coti.FOLIO,res.EMAILDESC,r.PeopleSoft,r.CurrentDep,Coti.NOMBRE,Coti.SUPERVISOR,envio.PROVEEDOR,app.CUENTA,Coti.ITEM,Coti.CANTIDAD,Coti.NUMSUP,Coti.ID
from REGCOTIZACIONES as Coti
inner join CUENTAS as R on R.PeopleSoft= Coti.DEPARTAMENTO
inner join RESPROVEEDORES as res on res.FOLIO = Coti.FOLIO
inner join COTIENVIADA as envio on envio.FOLIO = res.FOLIO
inner join APROVNIVEL1 as app on app.FOLIO = Coti.FOLIO
where envio.REFERENCIA = 7162510 and Coti.FOLIO = 270
```

esta son los datos de las tablas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tienes dos tablas con 2 campos iguales, no esta duplicando nada.

Comment: puedes agrupar tu consulta total, o hacer una subconsulta con solo algunas tablas y agruparla, o que solo te regrese 1 registro

Comment: me deberia de mostrar dos ya que mi tabla principal por asi decirlo es REGCOTIZACIONES y hay dos registros

Comment: la ultima tabla que pones tiene dos registros con el mismo folio, entonces cuando hace el cruce hace 1 de el primer registro de tu tabla principal con 2 de la ultima tabla y luego otro cruce de el segundo registro contra los dos de la ultima tabla, es por eso que te genera 4

Comment: bueno eso sera un problema ya que el campo CUENTA puede ser diferente, mismo folio pero cuenta puede 12, 2500, 15 etc o puede repetirse la cuenta en el mismo folio

Comment: y como sabe sql eso? sql agarra una fila.. la une a todos los registros de la tabla joineada que cumplen con la condicion.. para todas las filas y todas las tablas... o sea.. que tengan diferente cuenta no nos dice nada...

Comment: ok, verificare la logica de las tablas quizas tenga que cambiarlas